# Do Chinese embedded clauses have C head?

Tags: syntax, chinese

It is pointed out that in Huang, Li, Li  (2009:35)'s book *the syntax of Chinese*, the discourse functions that ma/ba/ne perform are only associated with matrix clauses.

*Ba* is for imperatives, *ma* for yes-no interrogatives, and *ne* for interrogatives containing question phrases such as shei ‘who’ and shenmo shihou ‘what time.’

What remains unclear is why CT (ba/ma/ne) in Chinese never occurs with embedded clauses.

Are there any other evidence showing Chinese lack (or not) complementizer in embedded clauses?  Within the framework of generative grammar, is that a problem?

Comment: I don't know very much about Chinese syntax, which is why this is a comment rather than an answer until someone better-informed can tell me if I'm totally off-base. But in English, there are some things that only happen in matrix clauses (topicalization, question inversion); these are often explained by saying we have special invisible complementizers that are only used in matrix clauses. So in your case, I would think Chinese has some overt complementizers that only appear in matrix clauses, and one or more invisible complementizers that only appear in embedded clauses. The reason you…

Comment: …can't use _ma_ and such in an embedded clause is because the C slot is already filled by something else.

Comment: @Draconis what kind of invisible C slot do you mean? hmm, sorry I am not very clear with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Generative grammar" is in fact quite a broad term that's used in a lot of different ways. Some generative theories are quite fanatical about "all languages underlyingly have exactly the same categories" while others invent new categories or drop old ones to better fit the data of a specific language.

In other words, some forms of generativism would insist that every language needs its clauses to be headed by a C, while others would say you need a strong reason to posit a C category for each individual language.

But that's an unsatisfying answer. So here's how I would personally analyze this—with a major caveat that I speak very little Chinese and have never studied its syntax in any depth.

First, I'm going to go on a short digression about English C's.

In English, we seem to have overt (i.e. actually-pronounced) C's in embedded clauses, but not in main ones. Some syntacticians thus say that main clauses in English have no C in them—we don't see it, after all, so why claim it exists at all? A main clause can be simply a TP (or IP if you prefer), with no C at its head.

Others disagree, because of question-inversion. It seems to be generally accepted that modals like "may" are of category T, and the subject moves to the specifier of T:

[image: tree for "I can do this" showing "I" at SpecT and "can" at T]

But in question inversion, the modal seems to move *further* left, past the subject:

[image: tree for "can I do this" showing "can" moving leftward, to the specifier of a mystery element]

(Alternately, we could say there's just no subject movement in this case, but then you need to explain do-support: "he made it" > "did he make it".)

What could this mystery element be? Well, it's in exactly the same place as a C node in embedded clauses. Why not just call it a C? Then everything falls nicely into place. English has two invisible C's that can be used in matrix clauses; one of them is the question-complementizer, which has a feature that summons the T to it, and the other is the statement-complementizer, which does not.

And now, as part of the process of solving an unrelated problem, we've also made the syntax of main clauses and embedded clauses work the same way. Neat! We just have to explain why these two can't be used in embedded clauses, which is easy enough: the embedded-clause complementizers have a special feature that's required by the embedding constructions.

Again, I don't know much about Chinese syntax. But it seems like this same notion of "invisible complementizers" could solve this problem quite simply. You have overt complementizers, like *ma*, that appear at C position in main clauses. But you also have an *invisible* complementizer, which has a feature that's required by the embedding constructions. This appears at C position in embedded clauses. And then you can't put *ma* there because the slot is already filled: generally speaking, a clause can only have one C.

Is this the only way to solve the problem? Not at all. You could also come up with a theory that says Chinese embedded clauses are actually TPs, so they have no C position at all. But this would be my first instinct, because positing invisible C's works so well for English, and there's a certain elegance to having main clauses and embedded clauses work the same way.

Comment: Thanks so much Darconis for clarifying it! What you have written is very lucid and easy to read.  I have a quick following up question.  According to Rizzi's split-CP theory, topicalized NP or other categories also are included in the CP. Since Chinese allows topicalized NPs in embedded clause, does it prove that it has an overt C?  Plus, I got noticed from my friend that C is not just complementizer in some extent because C is a more broder term than complementizer.  I am wondering what you think about these terms.

Comment: @Xia.Yili My understanding is that topicalized NPs move to adjoin to the CP, at least in English, since they can coexist with question inversion ("my car, did you see it?"). This would mean that a C category exists in the embedded clauses, to give the topics somewhere to move to—but it doesn't have to be overt, it could be invisible.

Comment: @Darconis Thanks again for helping me understand this question.  I see that C can be invisible both in the matrix clauses or embedded clauses.